# Querying Multiple Indexes (of different field mappings) causing Failed Shards Exception

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I am trying to create Coordinate Map Visualization in Kibana, using an Index Pattern which covers two Indices of ElasticSearch. One Index contains the location (lat/lon) info whereas the other contains live data from IoT devices relevant to these locations. Both these indices have different fields obviously.

The problem I am hitting is when I try to create Map, to see live data over different locations, it does not display anything rather, returns an exception **"5 of 10 shards failed"**. I have checked the response of `http://localhost:5601/elasticsearch/_msearch` (which I suppose is querying ES for the required data) and got the following object:

```
{
    "took": 51,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 10,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 5,
        "failures": [
            {
                "shard": 0,
                "index": "live-data",
                "node": "R68NHkrGSIqyk8TdlR5ZrA",
                "reason": {
                    "type": "query_shard_exception",
                    "reason": "failed to find geo_point field [location]",
                    "index_uuid": "tOogjd6PTja0DAJLKYLpDA",
                    "index": "live-data"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The locations are displayed over the map as pointers when I use single index only, though.

This obviously is because ElasticSearch is not being able to find `location` field in `live-data` index, but shouldn't it be able to match `location` field from the other index? As, both the indices have a common field named `"device_id"`

I guess this can be solved by setting `ignore_unmapped: true` while querying ElasticSearch, but I have no clue how to set this parameter within Kibana so that it requests ElasticSearch data with it while building Visualizations.

**ELK Version: 6.1.2**

Any help would be much appreciated.